# fixing a jquery horizontal scroller (simple)

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, horizontal-scrolling

I know there are some really pretty carousels out there, but I wanted a very specific one that mimics most flash carousels you see.

Here is what is looks like:
valums.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/menu/final.htm

And here is the article:
valums.com/scroll-menu-jquery/

Now, if you see my(Gideon) comment on the bottom, theres just one issue with this thing, and its, if I add a lot of images to the containing div, it messes up completely, the images flow to the next line of the document. Temporarily I implemented it like this with 2 divs : www.giddy.co.in but for my new site I need just ONE row of images.

Also, in my version the text/caption on the bottom doesn't show!

Thanks so much

Gideon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by setting a fixed width and height on your containing div with overflow:hidden.

You don't seem to have width set in your example, and your height is set to auto.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Its doesnt work! =( Also, Expression Web says this property is not supported by the current schema for the height property in sc_menu in the stylesheet. Whatever height I put in there doesnt make any difference. 

You can check this link and see what it looks like : giddy.co.in/temp

Basically Im looking for a horizontal scoller that scrolls when the  users mouse over pics. Also, the hover for the span captions dont work! =(